# How do I redirect the output of Python curses to a different display?

Tags: gnu-screen, ncurses

If the Python curses library takes control of the display, how do I specify which display (amongst multiple GNU screens) it should display to? So that I could code with curses in a live Python shell, and see the output in split screen?

Comment: that's one of those situations where adding that feature (namely [multiterm support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674542/how-do-i-redirect-the-output-of-python-curses-to-a-different-display#comment1273190_674543) to python) would probably be easier than any workaround you may use.

Comment: Thanks. How could that be done?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a feature of `curses`/`ncurses`; if you want to connect to a GNU screen session, you'll need to start your program in a `screen` session.

Comment: ncurses could do this using `newterm`, but Python's binding doesn't include that feature.

Comment: So there’s no way to code in curses in a live Python shell? You have to edit the script, then run it to see how it performs? It would be great just to send the output somewhere else, like display=2

Comment: @ThomasDickey yep, but that just says "if you happen to have ownership of two sets of tty file descriptors, you can use them both with `newterm(type, fd_out, fd_in)`, but not "you can attach to a screen session automatically"

Comment: @PeterElbert as Thomas says, not directly. But if you just want to display some statistics, why not append them to a file, which you monitor using `tail -f`, for example, or write them into a socket or named pipe?`

Comment: I don’t need to display statistics, I just want to learn using curses but I really like live programming to see the effect of each command one at a time. If I execute prewritten scripts I have to use a timeout function to make sure the screen is launching before it quits. I wonder if this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696818/how-to-i-make-python-curses-application-pipeline-friendly

Comment: @PeterElbert I don't understand your problem; you can do python doing curses in one terminal and interact with the python interpreter from something else. But if you run a curses-using software, then it's always going to be "initialize screen", "draw something on screen". If you want things to display for a while, no matter how you do it, you'll want your curses program to persist

Comment: I think the link I shared above shows ways to make sure that curses launches its viewer somewhere else - a workaround given that Python doesn’t have newterm - but it’s too sophisticated for me to understand

Comment: curses doesn't launch *any* viewer. Curses is just a library that interacts with a terminal (a "TTY") that you *give* it to him. So, really, as said, curses doesn't concern itself with displaying anything at all. All it does is allow you to put the right characters in the right places on a purely virtual terminal's "idea of what can be displayed". The actual displaying is done by a *terminal emulator*, for example `gnome-terminal`, or `alacritty` or `xterm`.